# Where is the general html template file?

Tags: templates, html

I use Wordpress 4.7 and I installed an accessibility module. This module requires pasting the following php code block before the body. I went through the mother-theme php files but didn't find something like html.php or html.tpl ... Should this file be created (and maybe also declared) somewhere?

```
<?php if(function_exists('acp_toolbar') ) { acp_toolbar(); }?>
```

Comment: You're looking for `header.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should paste that code in the header.php file. Just before the closing code  . And that should be done. And if it is asking for pasting the code in the template then find the specific page where you want to place it. There may be different template for different page.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for custom changes, when you update your theme it will likely break. Besides that, Md. Amanur Rahman is correct, and so is Patrik Alienus.